# How does the code following the constructor Thread() work?

Tags: java

```
Thread timer=new Thread(){
     public void run(){
         ...
     }

};
```

Here we are initializing an object using a constructor. But at the same time there's some code corresponding to the constructor.

It seems the constructor *body* is being defined when it is invoked. Shouldn't that be inside the `Thread{}` block?

Comment: This code creates an anonymous `Thread` subclass and defines its `run` implementation. There is no code "corresponding to its constructor".

Comment: You are using an anonymous class, have a read here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are declaring anonymous class where you are providing the implementation of run method at run time. It becomes advantageous when you have intention to use the implementation at single place other you go for subclassing

It has nothing to do with initializing an object using a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class extend Thread.class.

```
    class MyThread extends Thread{
    String name;
    public MyThread(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
    }
```

use:

```
    MyThread thread = new MyThread("hello");
    thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you're creating with new Class(){} is a child class which has extended Class; Here's an example

Test.java

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Tester tester = new Tester() {
        @Override
        public void TestingPurposes() {
            super.TestingPurposes();
        }
    };
}
```

Tester.java

```
public class Tester {

public void TestingPurposes(){/*empty*/}
```

}

It basically means creating Child.java which extends Tester.

```
    public class Child extends Tester {
    @Override
    public void TestingPurposes() {
        super.TestingPurposes();
    }
}
```

and, main method should be,

```
Tester tester = new Child();
```